# Where the finally is necessary?

Tags: c#, exception, finally

I know how to use try-catch-finally. However I do not get the advance of using `finally` as I always can place the code after the try-catch block.
Is there any clear example?

Comment: "as I always can place the code after the try-catch block." - that isn't the same as a `finally`; execution will never get there if the catch block doesn't pick the exception up  or rethrows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: This is actually not a great answer. On the other hand, maybe it *is* a good answer because it illustrates a perfect example of `finally` succeeding where a developer (i.e., me) might fail to ensure cleanup properly. In the below code, consider the scenario where an exception *other* than `SpecificException` is thrown. Then the first example will still perform cleanup, while the second will not, even though the developer may *think* "I caught the exception and handled it, so surely the subsequent code will run."

---

Everybody's giving reasons to use `try`/`finally` *without* a `catch`. It can still make sense to do so *with* a `catch`, even if you're throwing an exception. Consider the case* where you want to return a value.

```
try
{
    DoSomethingTricky();
    return true;
}
catch (SpecificException ex)
{
    LogException(ex);
    return false;
}
finally
{
    DoImportantCleanup();
}
```

The alternative to the above *without* a `finally` is (in my opinion) somewhat less readable:

```
bool success;

try
{
    DoSomethingTricky();
    success = true;
}
catch (SpecificException ex)
{
    LogException(ex);
    success = false;
}

DoImportantCleanup();
return success;
```

<sub>*I do think a *better* example of `try`/`catch`/`finally` is when the exception is re-thrown (using `throw`, *not* `throw ex`—but that's another topic) in the `catch` block, and so the `finally` is necessary as without it code after the `try`/`catch` would not run. This is typically accomplished with a `using` statement on an `IDisposable` resource, but that's not always the case. Sometimes the cleanup is not specifically a `Dispose` call (or is more than just a `Dispose` call).</sub>

Comment: and, of course, if an exception other than SpecificException is thrown, DoImportantCleanup won't happen.

Comment: You guys are right. I've added an intro paragraph addressing that point.

Answer (score 4):

You need a finally because you should not always have a catch:

```
void M()
{
    var fs = new FileStream(...);
    try
    {
       fs.Write(...);
    }
    finally
    {
       fs.Close();
    }
}
```

The above method does not  catch errors from using `fs`, leaving them to the caller. But it should always close the stream.

Note that this kind of code would normally use a  `using() {}` block but that is just shorthand for a try/finally. To be complete:

```
    using(var fs = new FileStream(...))
    {
       fs.Write(...);
    } // invisible finally here
```

Comment: Hmm, I still cannot see why I could not just place the fs.close as separate statement, ie not in the finally block.

Comment: @Tray13: Where would you place it so that the resource was cleaned up even if an exception is thrown, without a catch block?

Comment: @tray1 : If `fs.Write()` throws an exception, my `fs.Close()` _will_ run. That's the whole point of try/finally. In your suggestion, the file would remain opened.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost always used for cleanup, usually implicitly via a `using` statement:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(...);
try
{
    // Read some stuff
}
finally
{
    stream.Dispose();
}
```

Now this is *not* equivalent to

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(...);
// Read some stuff
stream.Dispose();
```

because the "read some stuff" code could throw an exception or possibly return - and however it completes, we want to dispose of the stream.

So `finally` blocks are usually for resource cleanup of some kind. However, in C# they're usually implicit via a `using` statement:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(...))
{
    // Read some stuff
} // Dispose called automatically
```

`finally` blocks are much more common in Java than in C#, precisely because of the `using` statement. I very rarely write my own `finally` blocks in C#.

Answer (score 3):

```
try 
{
    DoSomethingImportant();
}
finally
{
    ItIsRidiculouslyImportantThatThisRuns();
}
```

When you have a finally block, the code therein is guaranteed to run upon exit of the try. If you place code outside of the try/catch, that is not the case. A more common example is the one utilized with disposable resources when you use the `using` statement.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
}
```

expands to

```
StreamReader reader = null;
try
{
    reader = new StreamReader(filename);
    // do work
}
finally 
{
    if (reader != null)
       ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
}
```

This ensures that all unmanaged resources get disposed and released, even in the case of an exception during the `try`.

*Note that there are situations when control does not exit the try, and the finally would not actually run. As an easy example, `PowerFailureException`.

Answer (score 2):

The code put in the `finally` block is executed even when:

- there are `return` statements in the `try` or `catch` block
  **OR**
- the `catch` block rethrows the exception

**Example:**

```
public int Foo()
{
  try
  {
    MethodThatCausesException();
  }
  catch
  {
    return 0;
  }

  // this will NOT be executed
  ReleaseResources();
}

public int Bar()
{
  try
  {
    MethodThatCausesException();
  }
  catch
  {
    return 0;
  }
  finally
  {
    // this will be executed
    ReleaseResources();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't necessarily use it with exceptions. You may have `try/finally` to execute some clean up before every `return` in the block.

Comment: Uh, I though when there is a exception, only the try blocks ends. If the whole method ends, it will be clear to me

Answer (score 1):

The finally block always is executed irrespective of error obtained or not. It is generally used for cleaning up purposes.

For your question, the general use of Catch is to throw the error back to caller, in such cases the code is finally still executes.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block will always be executed even if the exception is re-thrown in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it is done in c#, but in Delphi, you will find "finally" very often. The keyword is manual memory management.

```
MyObject := TMyObject.Create(); //Constructor
try 
     //do something
finally
    MyObject.Free(); 
end;
```

Comment: Now onto the next issue: C# *does* have GC, so this issue is moot. Resource management is still an issue, but it's solved by `using` so nobody you usually don't need to type out a `finally`.

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs (or is rethrown) in the catch-block, the code after the catch won't be executed - in contrast, code inside a finally will still be executed.

In addition, code inside a finally is even executed when the method is exited using return.

Finally is especially handy when dealing with external resources like files which need to be closed:

```
Stream file;
try
{
  file = File.Open(/**/);
  //...
  if (someCondition)
     return;
  //...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Notify the user
}
finally
{
  if (file != null)
    file.Close();
}
```

Note however, that in this example you could also use *using*:

```
using (Stream file = File.Open(/**/))
{
  //Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, during the process you may disable WinForm...

```
try
{
this.Enabled = false;
// some process
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
this.Enabled = true;
}
```